# How to differentiate if difference between dates in weekly on monthly?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which employee's loan details are being saved. Some employee get loan on weekly basis and wish to return each installment weekly and some wish to return installments monthly.
I want to get the total duration on the loan period if employee wishes to return installments weekly then it should give output like `5 Weeks` or `10 Weeks` but if employee wishes to return installments monthly it should give result like `4 Months` or `15 Months`.

Here is the sample data

```
LoanID   DueDate     AmountToBePaid
2        2019-01-01  500
2        2019-01-07  500
2        2019-01-14  500
2        2019-01-21  500
2        2019-01-28  500

3        2019-01-01  1500
3        2019-02-01  1500
3        2019-03-01  1500
3        2019-04-01  1500
```

Here is what I've tried but it gives output in weeks no matter if the installments are to be paid monthly as for loan id 3.

```
SELECT 
  LoanId,
  DATEDIFF(WEEK, inst_start, inst_end) weeks 
FROM LoanMaster LM
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
      dateadd(month, -1,min(duedate)) inst_start, 
      max(duedate) inst_end
  FROM LoanDetail
) LD
ON LM.ID = LD.LoanID
```

Out should be like:

```
LoanId   Duration
2        4 Weeks
3        3 Months
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data strictly follow the rule that for the same LoanID the DueDates will be either only consecuctive weeks or only consecuctive months, then we can deduce the period by dividing the range with the row count:

```
SELECT 
    LoanID,
    case
        when datediff(month,min(DueDate),max(dueDate))=count(*)-1 
            then str(datediff(month,min(DueDate),max(dueDate)))+' Months'
        else
            str(datediff(week,min(DueDate),max(dueDate)))+' Weeks'
    end as Duration
FROM  LoanMaster LM
GROUP BY LOANID
```